# React Native update and get in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a small code for reading a bible for an app but I'm having trouble marking the text from the text selection.

I can play for the variable but it does not pass to the FlatList ..

Can you help me?

```
var highlightsUser = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 126; i++){
  highlightsUser.push({uid: i, start: 0, end: 0})
}

<FlatList
            data={ chapterData.verses }
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                paddingBottom: 15,
                width: '98%'
              }}>
                <Text style={{

                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  color: '#FFF',

                }}>{ item.number }</Text>

                <SelectableText
                  menuItems={["Marcar", "Favoritar"]}
                  highlights={[ highlightsUser[index] ]}
                  highlightColor='rgba(255,255,0,0.5)'
                  style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#FFF' }}
                  onSelection={({ eventType, content, selectionStart, selectionEnd }) => {
                    if(eventType === "Marcar") {
                      console.log(content);
                      console.log(selectionStart);
                      console.log(selectionEnd);

                      const myIndex = highlightsUser.findIndex((el) => el.uid === index);
                      highlightsUser[myIndex] = { start: selectionStart, end: selectionEnd }
                      console.log(`start: ${highlightsUser[index].start}, end: ${highlightsUser[index].end}`);
                    }
                  }}
                  value={ item.text }
                />
                
              </View>
            )}
          />
```

Comment: *marking the text from the text selection* What do you mean by "the text from"?

Comment: my problem is being in the transition to a FlatList updating an array.

Comment: <SelectableText
                  menuItems={["Marcar", "Favoritar"]}
                  highlights={[ highlightsUser[index] ]}

Comment: in the console.log(`start: ${highlightsUser[index].start}, end: ${highlightsUser[index].end}`); print perfect in the node prompt.. full code: https://pastebin.com/1fk14wji